# using scrapy to extract information from different sites

Tags: python, scrapy

I am new to scrapy and I spent the whole night trying to figure out how to use it for my project.
Suppose I have the following websites: 
www.amazon.com
www.ebay.com
www.buydirect.com

and I want to get the price of an item(say a tv) from the different sites. How would I do this using scrapy? I checked the documentation but it seems they were only using a single site. Could anyone show me how to use different sites with scrapy to get say even the title of the sites.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These web-stores have APIs - should be easier for you to get the necessary data.

If you want to go with scrapy anyway, note that:

- each of these web-sites have different html content and loading mechanism - it means different parsing rules, strategy for every site
- for every item you want to find you will have multiple results and prices
- you may have to deal with ajax-based pagination

It sounds better to have separate spiders for every site/store you need to scrape, pipeline the data into the database and analyze/combine after crawling.

Though, here's an example how you can get titles from amazon and ebay in a single spider. Note `allowed_domains` and `start_urls` are not set, `start_requests` method is used:

```
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider


class GoodsSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'goods'

    def start_requests(self):
        yield Request(url="http://www.amazon.com", callback=self.parse_amazon)

    def parse_amazon(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

        print hxs.select('//title/text()').extract()[0]

        yield Request(url="http://www.ebay.com", callback=self.parse_ebay)

    def parse_ebay(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

        print hxs.select('//title/text()').extract()[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never used scrapy (I've rolled my own web-scraper for more control), however it seems to be centred around [spider objects](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#using-our-item).

So, presumably, it would be a case of writing a pair of subclasses of [BaseSpider](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#basespider) and [Item](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html#declaring-items) for each domain you wish to scrape. So you'd have:

amazon_item and amazon_spider for amazon.com; and

buydirect_item and buydirect_spider for buydirect.com

As for finding the title of a page, scrapy appears to use [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xpath) to define extraction locations. Should you want to find the title, you would have to formulate a Xpath Query to search for a title tag which is a child of a head tag.